# mysql_query inside for loop syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get value from database, here is my code:

```
function client() {
    $code=$_GET['actvcode'];
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','0000');

    if (!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");

    mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
    mysql_select_db("test" ,$db);
    $query = 'SELECT client FROM cmum_codes WHERE code="'. mysql_real_escape_string( $code ) .'"';

    if (!($result = @mysql_query($query))) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    $str = $result;
    return $str;
}
```

I always get the word "Array", what is wrong?

Comment: I imagine you're doing this `echo client();` is that the case?

Comment: yes i'll get name of client from actvcode

Comment: Thanks for all
 
Joust I've Toggle

    $str = $result;
    return $str;

with 

    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $rows['client'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're only expecting one result (in which case you should add `LIMIT 1` to your MySQL query), you must use [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

```
return mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Which will return the row, so when you call the client function:

```
$client = client();
echo $client['field_you_want_to_echo'];
```

Of course, you should look into the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension instead of the deprecated mysql.

Comment: `function client() {
    $code=$_GET['actvcode'];
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','0000');
           if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
           mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
           mysql_select_db("test" ,$db);
    $query = 'SELECT 
              client
              FROM cmum_codes 
              WHERE 
              code="'. mysql_real_escape_string( $code ) .'"';
if (!($result = @mysql_query($query))) {
die(mysql_error());
}
return mysql_fetch_array($result);
$client = client();
echo $client['client'];
}`

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` doesn't return your resultset, it returns a MySQL resource.  You need to then use [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).  You shouldn't be using any of the mysql_ functions as they're deprecated.  Instead, use either MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You must use mysql_fetch_array($resul) and add it on a variable for exemple $array and use ... foreach to get result
 
Foreach($array as $str){ echo $str;  }